# Cascading Queries GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm starting to work with GraphQl on ReactJs/NodeJs project and i didn't find how i can put on cascade my query.

I have planet, spacecenter linked on planet, and flights linked on space center.
I would like to create this query

[image]

but i need to know the count of the flights, and i didn't find.

Could you help me please ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I undid what seems to be an accidental removal of much relevant information. Let me know if it was intentional, giving reasons, please.

Comment: It's intentionnal, i found one part of my problem, so i edited to find the answer of my second part problem

Comment: I see. Sorry. Please write that kind of edit explanation into the appropriate field. You can repeat the edit now (and I will leave it be), if you use the edit summary field for explaining now. Reducing a question to only one specific question is a good thing by the way. Sorry for getting in the way of that. But please embrace the "**Edit Summary**" fields idea. Good luck.

Comment: without explicit api/resolver support you can't query for counts ... but not required ... client receives arrays with length prop available f.e. `data.planets.spacecenter.flights.length`